# 14.04 doesn't want to turn on after suspension

Tags: 14.04, suspend, motherboard

I've met trouble in my Ubuntu 14.04. I suspend my computer sometimes. And seldom it's not started after suspension (it's powered, but screen is black after pressing any key, drugging mouse etc.). I can't go to another tty or do something else. I can just reboot by hardware button. After reboot I see these windows (clicking to `report problem` just close the window):

---

[image]

I catch this bug only on motherboard [GIGABYTE GA-H81N-D2H LGA 1150](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5020#ov).

I've tried to:

- reinstall `libc6` and `gnome`
- patch kernel version to `3.16.0-45`

**UPDATED**

Sometimes I get this screen after turning on after suspension.

[image]